# Recursively remove xml nodes using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, file-io, linq-to-xml

Fairly new to Linq to XML How does one remove **xml node**( recursively using relation ) and **save** the document.

Structure of the xml cannot be altered as it comes from service.Below is the xml from a tasks service. Every task can have nested tasks for which there might be one or more nested tasks. Nesting is intended to be upto `N level`.

- When one of parent tasks are removed using linq to xml how do i remove all of it's children?
- How do i know all the nodes where successfully removed?

Xml:

```
<Tasks>
  <Task ID="1">Clean the Room</Task>
  <Task ID="2">Clean the Closet</Task>
  <Task ID="3" ParentId="2">Remove the toys</Task>
  <Task ID="4" ParentId="3">Stack action Figures on Rack</Task>
  <Task ID="5" ParentId="3">Put soft toys under bed</Task>
</Tasks>
```

In above xml when `taskId=2` is removed, it's sub-tasks namely `Id = 3` should be removed. Since `3` is removed it's subtasks `4` and `5` should be removed as well.

Comment: I don't understand your structure.  You state that if `Task=1`, `2,3,4,5` should be removed, yet none of them have a `ParentID=1`. Did you mean `Task=2` ?

Comment: @ErikPhilips sorry for the confusion. Task is related to another task through parentid attribute. So when task with `ID = 2` is removed it's children (tasks with `ParentId = 2`) should also be removed. this process goes on until there are no nodes for the currently deleted task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that with the xml:

```
<Tasks> 
  <Task ID="1">Clean the Room</Task>
  <Task ID="2">Clean the Closet</Task>
  <Task ID="3" ParentId="2">Remove the toys</Task>
  <Task ID="4" ParentId="3">Stack action Figures on Rack</Task>
  <Task ID="5" ParentId="3">Put soft toys under bed</Task>

  <Task note="test node" />
  <Task ID="a" note="test node" />
</Tasks>
```

If `Task ID=2` is removed, here is one solution:

```
// tasks = XDocument.root;

public static void RemoveTasksAndSubTasks(XElement tasks, int id)
{
  List<string> removeIDs = new List<string>();
  removeIDs.Add(id.ToString());

  while (removeIDs.Count() > 0)
  {
    // Find matching Elements to Remove
    // Check for Attribute, 
    // so we don't get Null Refereence Exception checking Value

    var matches = 
        tasks.Elements("Task")
             .Where(x => x.Attribute("ID") != null
                         && removeIDs.Contains(x.Attribute("ID").Value));

    matches.Remove();

    // Find all elements with ParentID 
    // that matches the ID of the ones removed.
    removeIDs = 
        tasks.Elements("Task")
             .Where(x => x.Attribute("ParentId") != null
                         && x.Attribute("ID") != null
                         && removeIDs.Contains(x.Attribute("ParentId").Value))
             .Select(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value)
             .ToList();

  }
}
```

Result:

```
<Tasks> 
  <Task ID="1">Clean the Room</Task>

  <Task note="test node" />
  <Task ID="a" note="test node" />
</Tasks>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following answer

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("task.xml");
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("Task")
        let attr = node.Attribute("ID")
        let parent = node.Attribute("ParentId")
        where ((attr != null && attr.Value == "3") || (parent != null && parent.Value == "3"))
        select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: I think this removes `Task` node with `ID = 1`, that's not what i asked for. Since task with ID = 1 is removed, How do i remove it's dependent tasks? tasks with `parentId = 1` and tasks that have parent id equal to tasks whose parentId = '1'? got it

Comment: I have edited his answer for the comparison of parent id attribute too in the where linq. Also, dere needs to be a null check on parent ID attribute