# How to remove a Node from XML Node List using C#

Tags: c#, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

[image]I am having a XmlNodeList xnlSubParam

```
              XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
              xDoc.Load(somexml);
              XmlNode xnParamList = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//tag");
              XmlNodeList   xnlSubParam = xnParamList.SelectNodes("subparam");
```

Now xnlSubParam will contain a list of nodes

How to get the Node attributes and how to delete a node from the list.I jut want to Delete the Subparam list.. from xnlSubparam how to do this ?
                 In my xml i have a Element Named  Inside the  inside

```
              <subparam name="test1" displayname="Test1" type="BOOLEAN"/> 
              <subparam name="test2" displayname="Test2" type="BOOLEAN"/>
              <subparam name="test3" displayname="Test3" type="BOOLEAN"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to delete it from the document as well, or just the list? And could you use LINQ to XML instead? (I generally find it a nicer API than the old DOM API.)

Comment: I dont want to delete it from Document i just want to delete it from XmlNodelist xnlSubParam

Comment: checkout this link.. I found it doing a google search remove a node using LinqToXML - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378498/remove-xml-nodes-using-linq-to-xml

Comment: No sir its not working ... they gave for XmlDocument i dont need for that

Comment: Can you post that Image in a larger form..? one would need to have extraordinary vision to see that, where is the XML that you are working with..?

Comment: Your question is getting less and less clear. "I jut want to Delete the Subparam list" - you've *asked* for the `subparam` nodes...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way of mutating the `XmlNodeList` itself. I'd suggest you copy the nodes into a `List<XmlNode>`, which you can then mutate however you wish in the normal way:

```
List<XmlNode> nodes = xnlSubParam.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();
// Now work with nodes
```

To use these LINQ methods, you need a `using` directive:

```
using System.Linq;
```

This only works in .NET 3.5 and higher, of course (unless you're using LINQBridge or something similar).

Note that personally I'd use LINQ to XML throughout:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(somexml);
var nodes = doc.Descendants("tag")
               .First()
               .Elements("subparam")
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Nopes it doent work it shows problem near .Cast becas Cast is not comming in Xmnode..

Comment: @user1903774: It's an extension method - you'll need to a `using` directive for `System.Linq`. I'm assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, mind you - are you?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0 and I am using using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: I would also suggest that you show a small snippet of the XML that you have so that perhaps @Jon Skeet and others here can see what it is your are trying to Delete.. Jon is very knowledgeable btw

Comment: @user1903774: Well `System.Xml.Linq` isn't the same as `System.Linq`... you need a using directive for `System.Linq`. But it's not clear why you're using the old DOM API if you're *also* using LINQ to XML...

Comment: @user1903774: Um, I didn't vote you down, although it's not clear why you've added an image to your question.

Comment: That's not your XML.. do you have a snippet of the xml that you are working against..?

Comment: In my xml i have a Element Named <param></param> Inside the                       <param><subparam></subparam></param>  inside                      <subparam name="test1" displayname="Test1" type="BOOLEAN"/>
          <subparam name="test2" displayname="Test2" type="BOOLEAN"/>
          <subparam name="test3" displayname="Test3" type="BOOLEAN"/>

Comment: @user1903774: Please edit your *question* (rather than adding irrelevant comments to my answer) showing your XML (not screenshots) and giving a *clear* indication of what you're trying to achieve. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I want to delete one of this sub param in runtime

Comment: I give up at this point, I'm afraid. I've explained how you can copy your list of nodes to a `List<>` which you can then mutate however you want. It's not at all clear why you can't just use my answer - since I explained that you need a using directive for `System.Linq`, you've given no more information about why my answer wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I give up as well Jon I am not sure why individuals are so afraid to follow expert advise such as what you have given him.I am off to answer other posts

Comment: While using this ... this error occurs                       List<XmlNode> nodes = xnlSubParam.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();          Error 5 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1903774: Then you *haven't* got a `using System.Linq;` directive.